# how do I return new array every time I swap 2 values?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some quiz and I have an array which is looking like this one: `let a = [1, 3, 4, 2]`

Now I'm wondering how do I create a loop that returns three new arrays with 2 swapped values i.e: (`a[i] swapped with a[i+1]`)

I'm expecting to get 3 following arrays like below:

1. [3, 1, 4, 2]
2. [1, 4, 3, 2]
3. [1, 3, 2, 4]

What would be the approach creating the loop for this? I have been trying to loop through the array with map function and swapping values but found that I'm just confusing myself. Any constructive approach/solution with an explanation to this quiz would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you expect a loop to "return" 3 different values?

Comment: I think you have not tried much

Comment: Show us how you tried `map` and `slice`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map in a loop is all you should need

```js
let a = [1, 3, 4, 2];
let r = [];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    r[i] = a.map((v, index) => {
        if(index == i) return a[i+1];
        if(index == i + 1) return a[i];
        return v;
    });
}
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `for` loop:

```js
let a = [1, 3, 4, 2],
    result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {     // notice that the loop ends at 1 before the last element
    let copy = a.slice(0);                  // copy the array
    let temp = copy[i];                     // do the swaping
    copy[i] = copy[i + 1];
    copy[i + 1] = temp;
    result.push(copy);                      // add the array to result
}

console.log(result);
```